# Importing .so file made with Cython results in ImportError: ... undefined symbol

Tags: python, docker, cython

I have cythonised a chunk of code, which I know works on my usual machine.

However, when I transfer it and run it on another machine it is not working. My machine is running Ubuntu and the other machine is running Ubuntu within Docker.

The error is:

```
    from myFile import myFunction
ImportError: /myFile.so: undefined symbol: PyFPE_jbuf
```

The Docker environment is set up with the exact same dependencies as on my local machine, so I can't understand why this is happening!

Comment: Are you using the same releases of Ubuntu on your machine and on the Docker system? Same version of Python?

Comment: Yes, 16.04 Ubuntu, 64 bit, and Python 3.5.2. Using pip install -r requirements.txt on the same list of requirements

Answer (score 1):

This error is referenced with several scientific Python projects https://github.com/scikit-learn/scikit-learn/issues/7542 https://github.com/automl/auto-sklearn/issues/101 and is apparently related to multiple installations of NumPy, Cython or different C++ compilers.

Now, you should make sure that the environment is clean on both sides: no packages in `~/.local`, no setting for `PYTHONPATH` environment variable and only the system Python and system compiler, for instance. Then, also provide the full backtrace instead of the one error.

Comment: `~/.local` had a couple of scipy packages under python 2.7. But after I remove them the code still works on my normal machine. Neither machine has `PYTHONPATH` set as an environment variable.

I am using a virtual environment for both to avoid these kind of issues.

Comment: Did you get any solution @tombird?